# Has_many :through _ids not working with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a Post model with many authors through the AuthorAssignment model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :author_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :authors, :through => :author_assignments
    has_many :featured_authors, :through => :author_assignments, :conditions => "`author_assignments`.featured = 1"
end
```

Here is my problem:

When I call:

```
@post.featured_author_ids
```

The SQL query doesn't include my condition that 'author_assignments'.feature equal true.

```
SELECT `author_assignments`.author_id FROM `author_assignments` WHERE (`author_assignments`.post_id = X)
```

On the other hand, when I call:

```
@post.featured_authors
```

The condition is included in the SQL and the expected result is correct.

Thoughts?

Comment: I opened a new Rails ticket at: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6680-has_many-through-_ids-not-passing-conditions-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the DB you're using ie SQLite etc (not mysql).
In that case try:

```
:conditions=>["author_assignments.featured = ?",true]
```

Comment: Sorry. No luck. The `` only encapsulates the table name. When it's removed, it doesn't change the fact that the conditions aren't being included in the SQL statement.

Comment: which version of rails are you on?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Modifying the conditions doesn't seem to work. I took a look at the Rails source and the `ids` method created by the `has_many :through` relation doesn't seem to include any of the `where` conditions when the method is built.